# When using query, is putting text and number in same column possible?

Tags: google-apps-script

i'm using query to merge different type of data.
However, it seems like that when i use query, query just set the type of whole column acoording to its own decision.
So, below is what i'm trying to achive after query.

```
         A            B
    normal text>    text    
normal number>  12345   
normal text>    text    
date>           2023.6.3.   
currency>   100$
```

But, below is what i'm actually getting

```
    normal text>    text    
normal number>  12345
normal text>    (blank) 
date>           2023.6.3.   
currency>   100$
```

Is it possible to put numbers and text in same column when using query?

Query i'm using is simple as below :
`=QUERY('Sheet1'!A1:Q,"SELECT*WHERE A IS NOT NULL AND I > 0",1)`

Answer (score 0):

According to the QUERY function inline tip

> In case of mixed data types in a single column, the majority data type
> determines the data type of the column for query purposes. Minority
> data types are considered null values.

It's generally a bad idea to mix data types in a single column. If you absolutely have to, try using the FILTER function instead:

```
=FILTER(A1:Q, A1:Q<>"",A1:Q>0)
```

Keep in mind that dates are also numbers (0 is Dec 30, 1899).